# Getting 2 products in my woocommerce cart instead of 1

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

I've been trying to make an amp version of my site
most importantly my product pages
I'm using [ampforwp](https://ampforwp.com/) plugin, but as I added the link to add the product to the cart, it just adds two instead of 1, and I couldn't find why
there are no empty links or things that I found on stackoverflow before

link for one of my amp sample versions: http://hashtom.net/product/%DA%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%BE%D9%86%D8%AC-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A1-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C/amp/

btw it's a Persian site but I changed the button names to english so everybody could read them

it would be so nice if someone could help me out with this
thanks in advance

Comment: I think the one product is shown as optional purchase in the cart with the amount 0.

Comment: I guess not, everything including the add to cart button works completely fine on the main site, any other idea?

Comment: A bit hard in Arabic, don't you have English templates for this question?

Comment: @David sadly there are no English translations right now, but I would be able to translate any confusing part for you
as of now just take a look at this [picture](https://imgur.com/a/NY5hWPd)

Comment: Good that you posted the screenshot, I only get the bottom-part shown.
with the bottle and the other option left beside it, and the bright square with the red button. (sorry edited)

Comment: apart from that it's possible that even the message is shown twice the product is only added once. But sure that would be confusing.

Comment: first I should thank you for your time
second I should say that It gives the price for two, and also when you go to checkout, it still shows two in your cart, even checked the payment part, and it's so confusing for me

Comment: Have a look here and follow the link perhaps: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291217/edit-product-in-cart-woocommerce-instead-of-adding-new-one

here another link: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17858

Comment: checked them out, didn't have those issues

Comment: is it possible that something is messed up in your templates?

Comment: probably that would be the case, my theme is old and might not work well with new updates of woocommerce & amp
trying to contact the theme builder right now